# String values to Numeric Array

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to convert the string values to an int array, e.g.:

```
var s = '1,1,2';
```

to:

```
var a = [1,1,2];
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you trust the values in the string array or do you need to validate that each value is numeric?

Comment: I was thinking about using split then parseInt to make sure, the values should be ok though

Comment: If you trust the values, the solution in the first part of @Andy E's answer is the simplest and quickest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is a dynamic-typed language, which means that it might not be so important for those array items to be numbers.  If that's the case, you might want to consider just using `split()`:

```
var s = '1,1,2',
    a = s.split(",");
```

If it is important that they're numbers, then your best bet is to iterate over them afterwards:

```
for (var i = 0, max = a.length; i < max; i++)
    a[i] = +a[i];
```

There's also the ECMAScript 5th Edition method `map`, but it's not implemented in all browsers yet.

Comment: Do you need to validate the strings are numeric first or do you already know that they'll be valid?

Comment: Thanks, is there an advantage of using `a[i] = +a[i];` over `a[i] = parseInt(a[i])`?

Comment: @xylar: without a second argument for `parseInt`, there's a potential danger of numbers starting with a 0 being parsed as octals.  `+a[i]` is the equivalent of `Number(a[i])`, which always parses as decimal unless the number starts with `0x` (for hex).  Mostly, though, I use it because it's shorter :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
"1,2,3".split(",").map(Number);
```

And for those browsers that don't implement `map`, take an implementation like this one from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

`Array.prototype.map` is in ECMAScript5, so don't be afraid to augment `Array.prototype`.

Comment: +1 for the `map` idea - although the compatibility implementation would be a little slow compared to a standard loop.

Comment: Difference between loop and wrapped loop can be neglected.

Answer (score 1):

*If the data is secure*, you could use `.eval()`.

```
var a = eval( '[' + s + ']');
```

If you're not sure about security, you could use `JSON.parse`.

```
var a = JSON.parse( "[" + s + "]" );
```

...though you'll need to include a parser in browsers that don't support it natively.

Comment: Forewarning that if any of the values were invalid, a syntax error would be thrown - e.g. `1,2,3a,4`.  If you can trust the source, then I quite like the `JSON.parse` approach.

Comment: @Andy E: Good point. This works if you're expecting valid numbers. Though if something invalid finds its way in, a syntax error may be desired. Depends on how this is used I guess. :o)